# Adding two large numbers in assembly for DOS

Tags: assembly, input, addition

My program is taking the first input properly but creating a mess with the second input. I guess I need to clear up the garbage present on stack, but I'm not sure how to do it.

```
.model small
.stack 100h
.data
vari dw 0
vari2 dw 0
cons dw 1
display db 10 dup('$'),0ah,0dh

.code
input proc
    mov ax,0 
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,-1
    mov dx,0

tag1: 
    mov ah,01
    int 21h 
    mov bl,al 
    sub bx,48 
    push bx 
    inc cx
    cmp al,0dh 
    jne tag1 
    pop bx 
tag2: 
    pop bx 
    mov ax,cons 

    mul bx
    add vari,ax
    mov ax,cons 

    mov dx,10 
    mul dx 
    mov cons,ax 
    loop tag2
    ret
input endP

input2 proc
    mov ax,0 
    mov bx,0
    mov cx,-1

    mov dx,0 
tag5: 
    mov ah,01 
    int 21h 
    mov bl,al 
    sub bx,48 
    push bx 
    inc cx
    cmp al,0dh 
    jne tag5 
    pop bx 
tag6: 
    pop bx 
    mov ax,cons 
    mul bx
    add vari2,ax
    mov ax,cons 
    mov dx,10 
    mul dx 
    mov cons,ax 
    loop tag6
    ret
input2 endP

addition proc
    xor ax,ax
    xor bx,bx
    xor cx,cx
    xor dx,dx
    mov ax,vari
    mov bx,vari2 
    add ax,bx  
    mov vari,ax 

    mov ax,0 
    mov dx,0 
    mov ax,vari 
    mov bx,10 
    mov cx,0 

tag3: 
    div bx 
    push dx 
    mov dx,0 
    inc cx 
    cmp al,0 
    jne tag3  

    mov bx,offset display 
    mov dx,0
tag4: 
    pop dx

    add dx,48 
    mov [bx],dx 
    inc bx
    loop tag4
    mov dx,0
    mov dx,offset display 
    mov ax,0 
    mov ah,09 
    int 21h 
    ret 
    addition endP

main proc 
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax 
    call input  

    call input2
    call addition 
    mov ax,0 
    mov ax,4c00h 
    int 21h 
    main endP
end main
```

Comment: Consider properly formatting your code

Comment: reformat and remove unneeded blank spaces/lines. Also, include only a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that contains where the problem lies

Comment: use adc to add the high parts

Comment: Adding meaningful comments to the code would not only help us help you, but will help you organize and understand your own work better, too.  Also, it appears that the code is written for 16-bit DOS and is using MASM. It would be helpful to mention which tools you're using.

Comment: yes it is written for 16-bit dos and we have been asked by our instructor to use MASM.  I m using Emulator 8086 to compile and execute my programs .

Comment: There are no errors in the code, it shows no errors and runs. the thing is it does not take proper input. It only takes the first input properly and the second input always has issues

Comment: Can anyone of you please make a simple calculator for me using 16-bit architecture , which would take inputs of any large numbers and perform the basic arthimetic operations on it .